# using JSSC to read from a serial port. How do I use inputstream

Tags: java, compiler-errors, serial-port, jssc

I am using JSSC to communicate with a serialport. 
The data comes in 1 byte at a time. New string is started by carriage return/newline.

The string length is variable. (82 characters max)

Each string begins with #.

As the data comes in 1 byte at a time, I have to assemble the string. I tried using a bufferedreader and inputstreamreader from a RXTX example, but I was unsuccessful.

So my question is, how do I assemble the string byte by byte and refresh the string on ?

I need it to be 1 string at a time as it will be parsed.

I have tried googling various things:
"jssc inputreader bufferedreader example"
"jssc inputreader serialPort.readString()"
etc.

```
//Array list declaration 
static List<String> datat = new ArrayList<String>();

...
...
      public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event) {


                    try {
                        String getdata =  serialPort.readString(event.getEventValue());
                        //System.out.print(getdata);
                        String[] parts= getdata.split("\\r");

                          if(!datat.isEmpty()){
                              datat.set(datat.size() - 1, datat.get(datat.size() - 1) + parts[0]);
                         }
                          for (int i=1; i<parts.length; i++) {
                              if (parts[i].contains("\n")) {
                            if(!datat.isEmpty()) {
                                datat.clear();
                                System.out.println("data cleared");
                            }


                      } else if (!parts[i].equals("\\r") | !parts[i].equals("\\n")) {
                          datat.add(parts[i]); 
                          System.out.println(datat);
                      }
                      }








                    }


                    catch (SerialPortException ex) {                  
                    }    
        }
    }
```

Comment: It is far more probable that each message is *terminated* by a CR/LF, in which case what you are looking for is surely `BufferedReader.readLine()`. There is only one way to use an `InputStream`, and that is to read from it. Your code is nonsense and doesn't even compile. Unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

1. Declare an arraylist
2. Receive byte from serial port. If byte received is not new line add to arraylist otherwise convert arraylist into byte array
   These steps needs to be done in a while loop

Comment: See above edit. I tried clearing the array with a couple loops but to no avail.